# Make Jenkins aware of dependency between several changed projects

Tags: jenkins, build-process

I would like to know if it is possible to make Jenkins aware of dependencies between projects so that the most basic is build first and so on. Illustrating this with an example:

I have 2 projects Kernel and Web and Web has Kernel as a dependency (Kernel holds the services for database access, Web holds JSF and xhtml-files).  Jenkins is set up to automatically build Web after Kernel is completed.

The problem is: When I edit files in both projects and commit them Jenkins builds both simultaneously. But because Web needs the Kernel the build will fail every time. Only after the Kernel build succeded the Web build is triggered automatically and will succeed.

So my question is: Is it possible that Jenkins recognizes that both projects were changed and that Web needs Kernel to be built first and 
so that Jenkins does not even start the Web build but waits for the Kernel build to be finished first?

Comment: How come Jenkins builds both projects simultaneously if Web is triggered after Kernel has completed successfully?

Comment: Jenkins builds both because a build is also triggered when changes are commited. And I commit changes to both projects simultaneously.